# Android app latency between button click and operation completion

Tags: android, android-espresso, latency

I am trying to test my app and see whats the user percieved latency( Time between button was clicked - time at which operation like showing a text completed).

There are couple of ways to do it:

1. Espresso testing: Calculate time between UI operations
2. Log events and calculate time as a post processing
3. Manually keep a stop timer and calculate it.

> Question: Are there any tool bundled with android or anything that is in the market I can use to test latency.